# Angular Route Controller Infinite Loop

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html, ngroute, angularjs-ng-route

First off, I am just a beginner at angularJS. I have these files

**App.js**

```js
'use strict';

var app = angular.module('testApp', [
  'ngRoute',
  'ngCookies'
])

app.config(['$routeProvider',
  function($routeProvider) {

    $routeProvider
      .when('/login', {
        controller: 'LoginController',
        templateUrl: '../app/login/login.html',
        hideMenus: true
      })

    .when('/main', {
        templateUrl: '../app/main/main.html',
        controller: 'MainController'


      })
      .when('/sales', {
        controller: 'SalesController',
        templateUrl: '../sales/sales.html',
        hideMenus: true
      })
      .otherwise({
        redirectTo: '/login'
      });
  }
])

.run(['$rootScope', '$location', '$cookieStore', '$http',
  function($rootScope, $location, $cookieStore, $http) {
    // keep user logged in after page refresh
    var checkStorage;
    if ($cookieStore.get('testToken') != null) {
      checkStorage = $cookieStore.get('testToken');
    } else if (sessionStorage.testToken!= null) {

      checkStorage = $.parseJSON(sessionStorage.testToken);
    }
    $rootScope.globals = checkStorage || {}
    $rootScope.$on('$locationChangeStart', function(event, next, current) {
      // redirect to login page if not logged in
      if ($location.path() !== '/login' && !$rootScope.globals.username) {

        $location.path('/login');
      } else if ($location.path() == '/login' && $rootScope.globals.username) {

        $location.path('/main');
      }
    });
  }
]);
```

**Index.html**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no">

<html ng-app="testApp">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>testApp</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="content/bootstrap.min.css" />
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="content/main.css" />
</head>
<body>


 
                <div ng-view style="height:100%"></div>
 
    <script src="scripts/jquery-2.1.3.min.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/angular-route.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/angular-cookies.js"></script>
    <script src="app/app.js"></script>
    <script src="app/login/login.controller.js"></script>
    <script src="app/login/login.service.js"></script>
    <script src="app/main/main.controller.js"></script>


</body>

</html>
```

**login.html**

```html
<div class="login-form">
<div ng-show="error" class="alert alert-danger login-error">{{error}}</div>
<div class="login-box">
<!--ui-keypress="{13:'login()'} && form.$valid"-->
<form name="form"  ng-submit="login()" role="form" class="form-signin">
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="center logo"></div>
        
        <input type="text" name="username" id="username" class="form-control login-text" ng-model="username" placeholder="Username" required />
        <span ng-show="form.username.$dirty && form.username.$error.required" class="help-block">Username is required</span>

       
        <input type="password" name="password" id="password" class="form-control login-text" ng-model="password"  placeholder="Password" required />
        <span ng-show="form.password.$dirty && form.password.$error.required" class="help-block">Password is required</span>
    <div style="padding-left:5px;padding-top:2px;"><input id="chkRemember" type="checkbox" ng-model="remember" /> Remember Me</div>
    </div>
  
     <div class="">
        <button type="submit" ng-disabled="form.$invalid || dataLoading" class="btn">Login</button>
     </div>
     
</form>
</div>
</div>
```

**login.controller.js**

```js
'use strict';

angular.module('testApp')

.controller('LoginController', ['$scope', '$rootScope', '$location', 'AuthenticationService',
  function($scope, $rootScope, $location, AuthenticationService) {
    // reset login status
    AuthenticationService.ClearCredentials();
    $scope.login = function() {
      $scope.dataLoading = true;
      var rem = 0;
      if ($scope.remember) {
        var rem = 1
      }
      AuthenticationService.Login($scope.username, $scope.password, rem, function(response) {

        if (response.success) {

          AuthenticationService.SetCredentials($scope.username, response.token, rem);
          $location.path('/main');



        } else {
          $scope.error = response.message;
          $scope.dataLoading = false;
        }
      });
    };
  }
]);
```

**login.service.js**

```js
'use strict';

angular.module('testApp')
  .factory('AuthenticationService', ['Base64', '$http', '$cookieStore', '$rootScope', '$timeout',
    function(Base64, $http, $cookieStore, $rootScope, $timeout) {
      var service = {};

      service.Login = function(username, password, remember, callback) {



        $http.post('api/test/log', {
            username: username,
            password: Base64.encode(password),
            remember: remember
          })
          .success(function(response) {

            callback(response);

          });

      };

      service.SetCredentials = function(username, token, rem) {


        $rootScope.globals = {

          username: username,
          token: token

        };

        if (rem == 1) {
          $cookieStore.put('testToken', $rootScope.globals);
        } else {
          sessionStorage.setItem("testToken", JSON.stringify($rootScope.globals));

        }
      };

      service.ClearCredentials = function() {
        $rootScope.globals = {};
        $cookieStore.remove('testToken');

      };

      return service;
    }
  ])

.factory('Base64', function() {
  /* jshint ignore:start */

  var keyStr = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789+/=AA';

  return {
    encode: function(input) {
      var output = "";
      var chr1, chr2, chr3 = "";
      var enc1, enc2, enc3, enc4 = "";
      var i = 0;

      do {
        chr1 = input.charCodeAt(i++);
        chr2 = input.charCodeAt(i++);
        chr3 = input.charCodeAt(i++);

        enc1 = chr1 >> 2;
        enc2 = ((chr1 & 3) << 4) | (chr2 >> 4);
        enc3 = ((chr2 & 15) << 2) | (chr3 >> 6);
        enc4 = chr3 & 63;

        if (isNaN(chr2)) {
          enc3 = enc4 = 64;
        } else if (isNaN(chr3)) {
          enc4 = 64;
        }

        output = output +
          keyStr.charAt(enc1) +
          keyStr.charAt(enc2) +
          keyStr.charAt(enc3) +
          keyStr.charAt(enc4);
        chr1 = chr2 = chr3 = "";
        enc1 = enc2 = enc3 = enc4 = "";
      } while (i < input.length);

      return output;
    },

    decode: function(input) {
      var output = "";
      var chr1, chr2, chr3 = "";
      var enc1, enc2, enc3, enc4 = "";
      var i = 0;

      // remove all characters that are not A-Z, a-z, 0-9, +, /, or =
      var base64test = /[^A-Za-z0-9\+\/\=]/g;
      if (base64test.exec(input)) {
        window.alert("There were invalid base64 characters in the input text.\n" +
          "Valid base64 characters are A-Z, a-z, 0-9, '+', '/',and '='\n" +
          "Expect errors in decoding.");
      }
      input = input.replace(/[^A-Za-z0-9\+\/\=]/g, "");

      do {
        enc1 = keyStr.indexOf(input.charAt(i++));
        enc2 = keyStr.indexOf(input.charAt(i++));
        enc3 = keyStr.indexOf(input.charAt(i++));
        enc4 = keyStr.indexOf(input.charAt(i++));

        chr1 = (enc1 << 2) | (enc2 >> 4);
        chr2 = ((enc2 & 15) << 4) | (enc3 >> 2);
        chr3 = ((enc3 & 3) << 6) | enc4;

        output = output + String.fromCharCode(chr1);

        if (enc3 != 64) {
          output = output + String.fromCharCode(chr2);
        }
        if (enc4 != 64) {
          output = output + String.fromCharCode(chr3);
        }

        chr1 = chr2 = chr3 = "";
        enc1 = enc2 = enc3 = enc4 = "";

      } while (i < input.length);

      return output;
    }
  };

  /* jshint ignore:end */
});
```

**main.controller.js**

```js
'use strict';

angular.module('testApp')

.controller('MainController', ['$scope', '$cookieStore', '$http',
  function($scope, $cookieStore, $http) {
    var session;
    console.log('LOOPING CONTROLLER');
    if ($cookieStore.get('testToken') != null) {

      session = $cookieStore.get('testToken');
    } else {
      session = $.parseJSON(sessionStorage.testToken);

    }
   

    $scope.remove = function() {
      $cookieStore.remove('testToken');
      sessionStorage.removeItem("testToken");
    }
  }

]);
```

Based on the given files, the index.html displays the login.html correctly and with no errors. however upon login and the $location.path in login.controller.js executes, routing initiates and runs main.controller.js only to see in my the page inspector on my browser spams the console.log('LOOPING CONTROLLER') and doesnt load main.html in the template.

Did I miss anything? thanks for the help

**UPDATE**

I seem to have conflict with jQuery. Removing jquery makes the pages work fine except for the parsing. Any idea on what is causing the conflict?

Answer (score 0):

I would guess the problem is the `$location.path('/main');` call in your `$locationChangeStart` handler. Given that this handler is executed *before* the location changes, it looks like it would execute infinitely.

Comment: the $locationChangeStart is located at app.js. it also executes. I am not sure why it loops the main.controller.js infinitely

Comment: Hmm let me have another think.

Comment: weird but after the $location.path it should execute the .run in the app.js right? it's not executing that function based on my debugging

Comment: Hmm, what isn't being executed?

Comment: this in app.js after the $location.path it should execute right due to refresh?
.run(['$rootScope', '$location', '$cookieStore', '$http',
    function ($rootScope, $location, $cookieStore, $http) { ***code here***}

Comment: You have a log there and it's not being printed?

Comment: yes I have put a log there. It only runs on initial loading then after I login that function doesnt give the log. and unleashes the infinite log in main.controller.js

Comment: That's expected.. `app.run` is only executed once. You should see the `$locationChangeStart` handler executed multiple times though.

Comment: I would put some logs before each call to `$location.path("...")`.

Comment: the $locationChangeStart is within app.run. Is that wrong?

Comment: there is only one $location.path on my current setup in the login.controller.js. it returns a log therefore the issue is narrowed down to app.js?

Comment: There are two more in app.js.

Comment: it does not execute even before the condition in app.js

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. Are you saying the `$locationChangeStart` handler never executes?

Comment: my bad I forgot to clear the cache, I have checked that the $rootScope.Globals.Username results as undefined. Maybe that causes the infinite loop still I don't know why. the link retains index.html#/main